# QNetworkReply not receiving data in Windows but works in Linux

Tags: c++, json, windows, qt, bitcoin

On Linux and Mac OS X Qt, wallet builds perfectly and works. On Windows, Qt wallet builds, but the Coinbase API call, which pulls `btc_gbp` price data, doesn't work.

Full source available [here](https://bitbucket.org/Sterlingcoin/sterlingcoin-linux-source).

```
//Coinbase API
const QString apiCoinbasePrice = "https://api.coinbase.com/v1/currencies/exchange_rates";

// THE CALL
void PoolBrowser::coinbasePrice(QNetworkReply* response)
{
mValue jsonResponse = new mValue();
QString apiResponse = response->readAll();

//Make sure the response is valid
if(!read_string(apiResponse.toStdString(), jsonResponse)) { return; }

mObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.get_obj();

_dBtcPriceCurrent =  QString::fromStdString(getPairValue(jsonObject,  "btc_to_gbp").get_str()).toDouble();

updateLabel(ui->lblOverviewBtcGbpPrice,
            _dBtcPriceCurrent,
            _dBtcPriceLast,
            QString::fromUtf8("£"),
            2);

_dBtcPriceLast = _dBtcPriceCurrent;
_dScPriceLast = _dBtcPriceCurrent * _bittrexMarketSummary->getLastCurrent(double());
```

Comment: Did you ship OpenSsl with your application on Windows? You need it for HTTPs as a dynamic library. On most Mac and Linux installations it is available system-wide.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful description of the problem.  What are the error messages?  What is happening when you step through the code in your debugger?

Comment: It's simply not getting a resonse from the JSON call from the Coinbase API in Windows. Works in Linux and Mac.